# What is different between Winform and Webform TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, treeview

I'm a new to webform C#.
I use `TreeView in Webform`, it seems `AfterSelect Event`, `Tag`, `Name` properties don't exist? I cannot get data from TreeView without that properties. Is there any equivalent properties???

And what is different between two `TreeView`???

Comment: What's different between feature ABC in `winforms` and similar feature XYZ in `webforms`? - winforms is a (really old) Windows application UI framework. WebForms is an ASP.Net Web UI framework, which renders HTML content. these are completely different concepts. You should read about `desktop vs Web` and the related programming techniques and paradigms and not try to force an extraneous paradigm into a framework that's not intended for that.

Comment: I already know that feature. But sorry dear, I am a new to Webform, so that I cannot find the equivalent properties in Webform. Poor me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [WinForms TreeView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) documentation and [WebForms TreeView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) documentation to find out.

The WinForms `AfterSelect` event is probably most equivalent to the `SelectedNodeChanged` event of the WebForms tree.

The WinForms `Name` property is equivalent to the `ID` property of the WebForms tree.

The Winforms `Tag` property can be replicated in the WebForms tree by using the `Value` property or `ToolTip` property, but it is not a direct analog.

Answer (score 0):

In the front-end:
`<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>`

In the code behind:

```
private void AddChildNode(TreeNode parentNode, int parent)
{
   string st = "SELECT * FROM Peoples WHERE ParentID=" + parent.ToString();
   SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
   myConnection.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter myDataAdpter = new SqlDataAdapter(st, myConnection);
   DataTable tb = new DataTable();
   myDataAdpter.Fill(tb);
   myConnection.Close();
   foreach (DataRow dr in tb.Rows)
   {
     TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
     node.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
     node.Value = dr["ID"].ToString();
     int childNode = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);

     if (parentNode == null || parent == 0)
     {
       AddChildNode(node, childNode);
       TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
     }
     else
     {
       AddChildNode(node, childNode);
       parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
     }
   }
}
```

In the Page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
           TreeNode node = null;
           AddChildNode(node, 0);
      }
}
```

That code work with SQL below:
Peoples
**ID**   | **Name**   | **Date of birth**  | **Gender** | **Address**    | **PhoneNumber**    | **ParentID** |
36  | Charan Cline  | 02-03-1990    | Male  | US        | 0
37  | Audrey Cline  | 12-05-1980    | Female    | US        | 36
38  | Kris Cline    | 12-02-1985    | Female    | US        | 36

**“Peoples”** is the name of your table, and **"ParentID"** is the name of Parent ID column:
*string st = "SELECT * FROM Peoples WHERE ParentID=" + parent.ToString();*

Focus to query: 
*“SELECT * FROM Peoples WHERE ParentID=” + parent.ToString();*
Your change Peoples by table, and change ParentID by your ParentID column.
This is what the AddChildNode do:
MainNode -> Parent -> All Childs (Parent) -> All Child of All Child -> …

***Make all value of column ParentID is not null, use 0.***